# Fast Convolution Output too big?

Tags: c, fft, convolution

I'm trying to convolve a data set with a Lorrentzian curve generated within the program. I'm using convolution theorem (FFT input and response functions, multiply together and inverse transform the result). It all seems to be going fine and the output looks pretty much how it should, but the data points are far larger than the input signal.

For example, input of a rectangular pulse of height 0.5 produces a convolved output of height ~200. Can anybody see a reason why this might happen? (I intended to attach graphs of the output but I don't have enough reputation points).

My convolution algorithm is as follows. The FFT function I'm using has been well tested, I'm pretty sure that's not the problem:

```
double* convolve(double *input, double *response, unsigned long length)
{
unsigned long i, N = 2*length;
double *ans = (double*)malloc(2*(length+1)*sizeof(double));
double tempr;

printf("Length is %lu\n", length);

printf("Transforming input\n");
FFT(input, length, 1);
printf("Transforming response\n");
FFT(response, length, 1);

for (i=0; i<N; i+=2)
{
    ans[i] = input[i]*response[i] - input[i+1]*response[i+1];
    ans[i+1] = input[i+1]*response[i] + input[i]*response[i+1];
}

printf("Reverse transforming\n");
FFT(ans, length, -1);

/*Re-order array*/

for(i=0; i<length; i+=2)
{
    swap(ans[i+1], ans[N-(i+1)]);
    swap(ans[i], ans[N-i]);
}
return(ans);
}
```

Comment: It depends completely on the amplitude of your filter kernel (i.e. `response` here); are you sure you normalized that correctly?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I checked that just after posting. A lorentzian generated by the program with a FWHM of 0.2 has a height of ~3. This is correct for a normalised Lorentzian as described here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html. Somehow an input amplitude of 0.5 and a response amplitude of 3 blows the thing up to 200?

Comment: Try to replace the for loop by `ans[i]=response[i];ans[i+1]=response[i+1];` to see if `FFT(...,-1)` correctly scales your signal. Moreover, you allocate `2*(length+1)` double, but your for loop stops at `(2N-2)+1`...Supposing that the additional space may be useful for symetric frequencies : try to go up to `N+1` in the for loop !

Comment: Ok, done some more work on it, I wasn't padding properly (though the output was identical for this particular function). Pasting the two functions into origin and performing a convolution (i.e. using commercial convolution software) spits out a transform of this magnitude anyway, so I presume the output is correct? FFT(..., -1) does correctly scale the output. The extra malloced space was only really a sloppy fix for an array overstep previously, I ought to fix it, but I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: I do not know how magnitude is defined. But if it occurs at boundaries, it may be a Gibbs phenomenon, or something related to the truncation of Fourier series (ringing artefacts).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts. It seems that the Fourier transform of the Lorentzian function is known analytically. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformLorentzianFunction.html. The best way to go may be to use it directly in the fourier space ! I do not expect this to solve completely the problem...